# Navigate from HTML Page to MVC View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html

I have a home.html page from where I have to redirect the user to a View in mvc on button click.
How can I do that ?

Comment: any reason you can't use `<a href="my-mvc-page">`?

Answer (score 0):

Use some Jquery code on button click as shown :

```
$('#buttonid').on('click',function(){
  window.location.href = "/controllername/actionname";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

By following code you can do this

```
$('#buttonid').on('click',function(){
  $(location).attr('href','/controllername/actionname');
});
```